# Обжигающе(-)оранжевый

Tags: раздельно-дефис

Подскажите, будьте добры, через дефис или раздельно?
Обжигающе(-)оранжевый

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если обжигающе-оранжевый – это  ярко-оранжевый, то сложное прилагательное пишется через дефис (как оттенок цвета).

Раздельно написание чаще встречается в сочетаниях: **обжигающе холодный, обжигающе горячий.** В то же время переносное значение также возможно:  **обжигающе прекрасный, обжигающе красиво.** Поэтому вполне возможно авторское понимание этого слова в метафорическом, а не в обычном смысле.

Примеры:

Она могла и должна была состояться, воссиять, выстрелить в мае в самое солнце **обжигающе белой и розовой свечой**. [Виктор Козько.  1999.05.15]

**На обжигающе-красном фоне** налившегося заревом неба, рядом с игрушечной церковью под пылающим на закате крестом пронзительно чернела кривая высокая виселица. [Сергей Бабаян.  (1994)]

Примеры

Comment: Поздравляю Вас, Sharon, с самой высокой (и заслуживающей самого высокого уважения!) репутацией на сайте. Снимаю все шляпы и все вообразимые  и невообразимые — все! — головные уборы. Кланяюсь вашему опыту и вашим знаниям. P. S. Первое сентября — это знаменательный день (во всех отношениях).

Comment: Римма, я тронута  вашим вниманием, спасибо огромное! Я думала, что никто не заметит, да и сама смотрю на цифру 100 с некоторым недоумением, она мне кажется какой-то странной.  Вспомнила наш разговор с модератором, даже хотела спросить: "А где же  обещанный приз-сюрприз?" https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/469/Как-можно-финансово-благодарить-участников

Comment: Присоединяюсь к поздравлениям! Радуйте нас и дальше такими разнообразными и глубокими ответами и вопросами!

Comment: Спасибо, буду радовать, если получится, но  и вы меня, пожалуйста,  тоже радуйте.

Answer (score 2):

Из Розенталя:

> Пишутся через дефис сложные прилагательные, обозначающие оттенки
> цветов...

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/30.htm

В вашем случае едва ли подразумеается, что от "оранжевости" кого-то буквально "обжигало"; здесь (пусть и нестандартным образом, эмоционально) обозначен *оттенок цвета*, поэтому через **дефис**, как и в случае обычного "ярко-оранжевого".